# How to disable grey highlighter/text selector in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

[See screenshots] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtk6c.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VakPX.png) When I click on a part of my code, a grey highlighter comes on the whole letter instead of between the letters. So when I start typing, my new code completely overrides the one I just wrote.

I don't know how to disable or get around this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you need to toggle your Insert key...

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The Insert key is on your keyboard.

Comment: Oh gosh it really was that easy huh :" thank you